# Magento display out of stock products when quantity is zero

Tags: magento

I want to display products in search when quantity is zero. I have set Show out of stock to Yes from Sales->Inventory but products that have quantity is zero, are not coming search result.

Can anyone advise. Is there any thing, I am missing

Comment: well at least I am not the only one who asks Magento questions on this site and gets completely ignored...